# When did England make a statute that barred foreigners from inheriting the throne?

Tags: england, law, royalty, royal-succession

According to Iain Moncreiffe in his book [The Highland Clans](https://archive.org/details/highlandclansdyn00monc), he says this.

> “By the fourteenth century it had become common law (in both England and Scotland) that a person who was not born in the liegeance of the Sovereign, nor naturalised, could not have the capacity to succeed as an heir”

However Wikipedia says this

“It was not common law but a 15th-century statute that restricted the English crown to those in the liegeance of the Sovereign”

So which is correct? Was it done in the 14th or 15th century?

Comment: Which Wikipedia article?

Comment: This is very dubious, as: (1) the supremacy of Parliament is not established until the Glorious Revolution in 1688, long after the period in question; and (2) it has always been a fundamental tenet of all Westminster democracies that the current Parliament is supreme over all previous Parliaments.

Comment: The English laws of succession were governed by Parliamentary statue from fairly early. (You'll recall that every time Henry VIII fiddled with the succession, he had it ratified by Parliament.  See abstract of http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100540503)  This is not to say that those statutes could not be changed!  Again, cf Henry.

Comment: Citation for the Wikipedia claim is really important.  I can't find that quote in Wikipedia, but it occurs in [Jacobite Succession](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Jacobite_succession.html) as a quote from Moncreiff.  Can you check the citation?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace The paragraph seems to have been added to an an [old version](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Jacobite_succession&diff=prev&oldid=286507549) of the page on the Jacobite succession, dated 27 April 2009. It was added by an anonymous editor but without citation. The entire section was subsequently removed, which is why it's no longer searchable.

Comment: Even if such a statue exists, it has been violated several times.

Comment: If there was such a law, then the reigns of William III, George I, and George II were not in accordance with it.

Comment: @Alex There certainly was such a statute, passed in 1351 (see my answer below).  Had the original statute remained in force then it would indeed have been violated several times. However, there have actually been a number of replacement statutes over the years since (as is normal with statutes passed by Parliament), although the principle of _jus sanguinis_ operating alongside the  _jus soli_ remains.

Comment: It couldn't have been before 1727 (unless a statute was enacted, then repealed or ignored), since that's when the foreign George II ascended the throne.

Answer (score 8):

### tl; dr

[Iain Moncreiffe of that Ilk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iain_Moncreiffe) is correct. The '*common law*' he is referring to for England dates to a legal judgement in 1321.

The *Statute*, however, dates to 1351 (not the fifteenth-century as claimed in your quote.)

So, a fourteenth-century statute, *De Natis Ultra Mare*, **did** restrict the English crown to those in the *liegeance* of the Sovereign.  **However**, that statute replaced the earlier Common Law based on the judgement of *Rex v. Philip de Beauvais* in 1321.

---

The paragraph in your quote from Wikipedia seems to have been added to an an [old version](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Jacobite_succession&diff=prev&oldid=286507549) of the page on the *Jacobite succession*. It was added by an anonymous editor on 27 April 2009, but without citation. The entire section was subsequently removed, which is why it's no longer searchable, although the claim is now repeated on a number of other sites.

That is regrettable, since the paragraph is incorrect in every important respect!

---

However, I think the root of the problem here may actually lie in a misunderstanding of what constitutes **Common Law**, and how it differs from **Statute Law**.

***I apologise in advance for the fact that what follows will, of necessity, involve a certain amount of 'legalese'.***

---

[Common Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_law) is the part of English law that derives from custom-and-practice and judicial precedent (i.e. previous court rulings), rather than statutes passed by Parliament.

---

The principle that inheritance was limited to a person born in the *liegeance* of the Sovereign, or naturalised, dates to a case brought to the Eyre of London in 1321 (Rex v. Philip de Beauvais). The judgement in this case was that foreign-born persons were indeed excluded from inheritance (essentially because of the difficulty of proof), although the case hung upon the dual meaning of the word '*liegeance*'.

Philip de Beauvais inherited an estate from his father. The king's Serjeant, Geoffrey Scrope, argued that Philip's father was born outside of the king's *ligeance*, or 'territories'.

> "Votre piere ne fut nient de la ligaunce d'engleterre"

- Keechang Kim: [Aliens in Medieval Law: The Origins of Modern Citizenship](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QidHO7WfRxMC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), Cambridge University Press, 2000, p139

Now, in the early fourteenth century, English lands belonging to foreign-born individuals automatically became the property of the king upon the death of that individual.

The attorney for Philip, a Serjeant Shardlow, argued that Philip's grandparents had been married in England, paid homage to the King of England, and died in the king's homage. Therefore, although Philip's father had been born in a foreign country, he was nevertheless technically born within the king's *ligeance* or '*loyalty and obedience*' (taking the alternative meaning of the word *ligeance*).

Although the judge initially ruled in Philip's favour, that ruling was overturned on appeal and Philip forfeited his inheritance to the king.

However, what matters here is that this judgement then became part of English Common Law.  It also meant that titles (technically including the Crown) could not be inherited by a person who was not '*born in the liegeance of the Sovereign, nor naturalised*'.

---

So, Iain Moncreiffe of that Ilk was entirely correct in his assertion about Common Law.

---

Now, [Statutory Law](http://Statutory%20law) in England were the laws passed by Parliament. Statutes often clarify and take precedence over Common Law.

---

The statute being referred to in this case is presumably [De Natis ultra Mare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_natis_ultra_mare) (25 Edw. III Stat. 1) 1351.  This Act superseded the earlier Common Law.

The text of the statute is available in Latin, with and English translation in [The Statutes: Revised Edition, Vol I, Henry III to James II, A.D. 1235-6 - 1685](https://archive.org/details/statutes00britgoog/page/n273), p175.  The relevant portion states:

> "... the law of the crown of England is, and always has been such that the children of the Kings of England, in whatsoever parts they be born, in England or elsewhere, be able and ought to bear the inheritance after the death of their ancestors; ..."
>
> "... And in the right of other children born out of the ligeance of England in the time of our lord the King, ... shall be from henceforth able to have and enjoy their inheritance after the death of their ancestors, in all parts within the ligeance of England, as well as those that should be born within the same ligeance. And that all children ineritors which from henceforth shall be born without the ligeance of the king, whose fathers and mothers at the time of the birth be and shall be at the faith and ligeance of the King of England, shall have and enjoy the same benefits and advantages to have and bear the inheritance within the same ligeance, as the other inheritors aforesaid in time to come..."

---

So, while the quote is correct that a statute restricted the English crown to those in the *liegeance* of the Sovereign (although it was a 14th century statute, rather than a 15th century one as claimed in the quote), in fact that statute simply replaced the earlier Common Law judgement of *Rex v. Philip de Beauvais* in 1321.

---

There is an excellent course, from the University of London and available on the Coursera platform, that offers an [Introduction to English Common Law](https://www.coursera.org/learn/intro-common-law) if you're interested in following up on the topic in slightly greater detail.

---

As an aside, this little known part of English law is often claimed to have established the principle of *[jus sanguinis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jus_sanguinis)* operating alongside the principle of *[jus soli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jus_soli)*, which in turn influenced Article II Section 1 of the U.S. Constitution which states:

> No person except a natural born Citizen, or a Citizen of the United States, at the time of the Adoption of this Constitution, shall be eligible to the Office of President; neither shall any Person be eligible to that Office who shall not have attained to the Age of thirty-five Years, and been fourteen Years a Resident within the United States.

- Adopted by the Philadelphia Convention on 17 September 1787.

(See, for example, [Natural Law and Birthright Citizenship in Calvin's Case](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d786/c289880aed7388106b8baddd0f8b3284fb34.pdf))

Comment: Superb answer.  I was aware of the distinction between common law and statue law, but I've never seen it explained so clearly.

Comment: Moncreiffe was probably referring to the the feudal law maxim,[_Nulle terre sans seigneur_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nulle_terre_sans_seigneur), in simple terms: "**no property without a liege**". It became English common law via that case (I'm assuming you read it as I haven't). In any case, that's the basis of this (common) law. From the question title, I believe OP might have confused inheritance of _property_ with that of _the throne_ (authority, Sovereign).

Comment: @JAsia I don't think so. The maxim _Nulle terre sans seigneur_ was about property ownership, while Moncreiffe is talking explicitly about _inheritance_.  Besides, the principle of _Nulle terre sans seigneur_ was established well before the fourteenth century.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Confused! The quote seems to **allow** inheritance by those born outside the *liegance*? And - before the Hanoverians, James I & VI was born outside the liegance. Am I being thick? ;-)

Comment: @TheHonRose Yes. Edward III was concerned about the effect of the 1321 Common Law on soldiers fighting for him abroad. So the law allowed inheritance by those born outside the _liegeance_ to parents who were _at the faith and liegeance of the King of England_, who might otherwise have been denied their inheritance by the 1321 ruling (and it secured the rights of the King's children wherever they were born!).  The rules on who could inherit the throne had been changed by later acts of Parliament by the time of James I & VI. And no, you're not being thick! Law is hard!

Comment: @sempaiscuba - I meant it as the _basis_ on common law of inheritance. But, yes, I do see your point of objection.

Comment: @TheHonRose I just re-read my last comment and realised how condescending it sounds.  I'm really sorry about that. I didn't mean to be condescending.  I just meant that law can be really complicated - it's the reason we need lawyers!

Comment: @sempaiscuba - not at all! I **was** confused - I blame global warming rather than old age ;-) - I considered the law as a profession at one time, but I'm emphatically **not** a detail person! No need to apologise, no offence taken. :-)

Comment: @sempaiscuba When was the statute formally replaced? Didn’t some people use the statute to argue against James VI of Scotland succeeding to the throne?

Comment: @JacobHarrison It was certainly replaced by Henry VIII's _Succession to the Crown Act 1533_ (which would be modified by the _Succession to the Crown, Marriage Act 1536_ and eventually superseded by the _Succession to the Crown Act 1543_).  There may also have been earlier acts that changed the 1351 statute.  In any case, the 1351 statute was no longer applicable when James VI/I ascended to the English throne in 1603.